# .htaccess, redirect to https of http url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, progressive-web-apps

If I have multiple domains (*.net, *.org, *.com) pointing to the same dir on the server with a single .htaccess file, how can I write a redirect that changes the url as well as redirects to the https:// secure connection of the site?

So if they visit http://korell.com, it goes to https://korell.com and if they visit http://korell.org, it does to https://korell.org. And so on and so forth.

I already have www.korell.* going to http://korell.* in the A records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: How could I make one more addition, excluding particular domains? So that  I can manually say for these two domains (korellsea.com and korellsea.org) do not redirect to their ssl versions, do nothing, but for korell.org and korell.net and korell.com redirect as you've done in your answer above?

Comment: You can exclude domain with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(korellsea\.com|korellsea\.org) [NC]` line before `RewriteRule`